# @Transactional not committing (Spring Mybatis)

Tags: java, spring, rest, mybatis, transactional

I have below Service:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW,isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void test(String idEntity) throws BaseException
{
    getCustomerInformationDAO().updatetm(idEntity);
}
```

This service has been marked as @Service annotation.

I am calling this service from a controller.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/test", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Override
public void test(@RequestParam("idEntity") String idEntity) throws BaseException
{
    monolithicService.test(idEntity);
}
```

Below Dao(this has been marked as @Repository) method:

```
@Override
    public void updatetm(String idEntity) throws BaseException
    {
    updateRecord( "customerinformation-update.updatelfcentitylDt", idEntity ); 
    }
```

Transaction manager has been marked as

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />.
```

With above changes, it doesnt commit the transaction, even if it is successful.

Can anyone help me with this...

Comment: can you show how you have configured your database connection?

Comment: defaultautocommit is false @GarimaGupta

Comment: Did you get any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with a similar issue for a whole day.

Just when I was borderline with insanity, I found out that when you use `@Transactional` in a test the rules are different: **by default, your changes are rolled back.**

Quick solution: add the annotation `@Commit` to your method, i.e.:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW,isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
@Commit
public void test(String idEntity) throws BaseException
{
    getCustomerInformationDAO().updatetm(idEntity);
}
```

You can read some details in the following text:

> One common issue in tests that access a real database is their effect on the state of the persistence store. Even when you use a development database, changes to the state may affect future tests. Also, many operations — such as inserting or modifying persistent data — cannot be performed (or verified) outside of a transaction.
>
> The TestContext framework addresses this issue. By default, the framework creates and rolls back a transaction for each test. You can write code that can assume the existence of a transaction. If you call transactionally proxied objects in your tests, they behave correctly, according to their configured transactional semantics. In addition, if a test method deletes the contents of selected tables while running within the transaction managed for the test, the transaction rolls back by default, and the database returns to its state prior to execution of the test. Transactional support is provided to a test by using a PlatformTransactionManager bean defined in the test’s application context.
>
> If you want a transaction to commit (unusual, but occasionally useful when you want a particular test to populate or modify the database), you can tell the TestContext framework to cause the transaction to commit instead of roll back by using the @Commit annotation.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testing

Comment: Downvote. Do you see @Test anywhere in the question? It's not a test class.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have two data sources using *MapperScan* that might be messing up a mybatis config. You need to add *SqlSessionFactory* and *SqlSessionTemplate*  as mentioned here http://mybatis.org/spring/getting-started.html.

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;
import org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean;
import org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate;
import org.mybatis.spring.annotation.MapperScan;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@Slf4j
@MapperScan(value = "com.abc.xyx.aaa", sqlSessionTemplateRef = "PrimarySessionTemplate")
public class MyBatisPrimaryConfig {

    @Bean(name = "PrimarySessionFactory")
    @Primary
    public SqlSessionFactory sessionFactory(@Qualifier("PrimaryDataSource") DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sqlSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return sqlSessionFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean(name = "PrimarySessionTemplate")
    @Primary
    public SqlSessionTemplate primarySessionTemplate(@Qualifier("PrimarySessionFactory") SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory) {
        return new SqlSessionTemplate(sqlSessionFactory);
    }
}
```